# @nestjs/websockets problema de conexión,

Tags: nodejs, socket.io, websocket, nestjs

Tengo un problema al actualizar @nestjs/websocket, tengo un servidor que proporciona una conexión simple para WebSockets con el único fin de decirle al mismo usuario en los dispositivos donde se encuentra conectado que se realizó una actualización, sea un su información o en cualquiera de sus datos.

Usando las versiones 9.0.0 de @nestjs/platform-express y @nestjs/platform-socket.io
todo funciona bien. pero al actualizar a las versiones 10.0.1 el cliente recibe un error 404 al intentar conectarse.

Traté de mirar en el repositorio de nestjs a ver si encontraba un change.log por si modificaron algo pero no me fue posible ubicar el change.log. Por lo tanto vengo a la comunidad a ver si saben algo y pueden ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

**-node 18.16.0 -  @nestjs/core 10.0.1 - OS windows 11 y debian 11 - soket.io 4.6.1**

> **app.gateway.ts**

```js
import { WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer } from '@nestjs/websockets'
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io'
import { ValidateSessionMiddleware } from './middlewares/validate-session.mdw'
import { wsGatewayValidateSessionUtil } from './utils'
import { SocketWithSub } from './types'

@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway {
 
    private userRooms = new Map<string, Set<Socket>>()
    @WebSocketServer() server: Server

    afterInit(client: Socket) {
        client.use(ValidateSessionMiddleware as any)
    }

    handleConnection(socket: SocketWithSub) {
        const { sub } = socket
        if (!sub) return
        socket.join(sub)
        if (!this.userRooms.has(sub)) {
            this.userRooms.set(sub, new Set())
        }
        this.userRooms.get(sub)?.add(socket)
    }

    handleDisconnect(socket: SocketWithSub) {
        const { sub } = socket
        if (!sub) return
        if (this.userRooms.has(sub)) {
            this.userRooms.get(sub)?.delete(socket)
            if (this.userRooms.get(sub)?.size === 0) {
                this.userRooms.delete(sub)
            }
        }
    }

    update(sub: string, data: any) {
        if (this.userRooms.has(sub)) {
            this.userRooms.get(sub)?.forEach((socket) => {
                if (wsGatewayValidateSessionUtil(socket)) {
                    socket.emit('update', data)
                } else {
                    socket.disconnect()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

> **app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { OrdersModule } from './modules/orders/orders.module'
import { FoodsModule } from './modules/foods/foods.module'
import { ClientsModule } from './modules/clients/clients.module'
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
import { config } from 'dotenv'
import { AdminModule } from './modules/admin/admin.module'
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt'
import { join } from 'path'
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static'
import { CategoriesModule } from './modules/categories/categories.module'
import { MulterModule } from '@nestjs/platform-express'
import { AppGateway } from './app.gateway'

config()
if (!process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
    throw new Error('MONGODB_URI not set')
}
if (!process.env.MONGODB_NAME) {
    throw new Error('MONGODB_NAME not set')
}
if (!process.env.JWT_SECRET) {
    throw new Error('JWT_SECRET not set')
}
@Module({
    providers: [AppGateway],
    imports: [
        ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
            rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
        }),
        MulterModule.register({
            dest: '../public/images',
        }),
        MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
            dbName: process.env.MONGODB_NAME,
            compressors: ['zlib'],
        }),
        JwtModule.register({
            secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
            signOptions: { expiresIn: '30d' },
            global: true,
        }),
        OrdersModule,
        FoodsModule,
        ClientsModule,
        AdminModule,
        CategoriesModule,
    ],
    controllers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```